# Reach permission asking dialog while testing in chrome

Tags: angularjs, html, protractor

The plan is to write e2e tests for a page which loads camera stream with html media capture. For these tests i would like to write different test cases depending on the answer is Allow/Deny/Close/Timeout. 
Is there a way to reach the dialog box with protractor or the only way is to mock the navigator object?